# Запись логов изменения значения переменной

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток. Нужно сделать такую фишку, но не знаю как:

Есть переменная, назовём её $f1 = 1;
При изменении её значения, например $f1 = 2;
Должно записываться значение этой переменной. 
Типа:

```
$f1 = 10;
$f1 = 20;
$f1 = 5;
```

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Объявите функцию и изменяйте переменную только посредством вызова этой функции

```
function set_f1($AVal) {
  global $f1;
  $f1 = $AVal;
  log('$f1 = ' . $f1);
}

set_f1(10);
```